# How do I make a LaunchAgent load at log in (via Lock Screen Hot Corner)

Tags: launchd

**What I want to do**

Load a LaunchAgent at log in, including logging in after locking my screen or the display goes to sleep.

**What my problem is**

My LaunchAgent loads when I log in after booting my Mac, or explicitly logging out. However, it doesn't seem to load when I log in after locking my screen. I can tell it doesn't load because it doesn't leave a log (neither standard output nor error).

**My setup**

- plist saved in `~/Library/LaunchAgents`
- plist contents (actual file paths redacted)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.deeeeekun.connectToSpeaker.agent</string>
        <key>Program</key>
        <string>/path/to/program</string>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
        <key>StandardOutPath</key>
        <string>/path/to/log/file</string>
        <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
        <string>/path/to/error/log/file</string>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: If you just locked your screen, you aren't logging in, just unlocking.

Comment: @unbeatable101 So is there a way to load launch agents when unlocking as well?

Comment: As far as I can tell from https://launchd.info/ and `man launchd.plist`, no

Comment: @unbeatable101 thank you, I'll look into 3rd party scripting apps then